# Normalize estimated probabilities from two logistic regression models

Tags: logistic, conditional-probability, normalization

I have built two logistic regression models predicting the probability of purchase of two products. (Product A and Product B)

For every customers, I want to choose the product that has the higher probability of purchase.

The overall purchase rate for these two products across all customers are different ( product A is a popular product and bought by more customers than Product B). The predicted probabilities are higher for Product A compared to Product B

What is the best way to normalize the predicted probabilities so that I can compare and select the best.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is a bit unclear. It seems that if you want to choose the product with "the higher probability of purchase" for each customer, then you just need to take the predictors for each customer and compare what your model produces for probabilities of choosing A and B. As you present your data, this will very frequently lead to A having higher probability. What do you hope to gain by "normalizing" the probabilities?

Comment: Can you clarify... customers either choose A or B exclusively? Or may they choose A, B, both, or neither?

Comment: @EDM,  Thanks for replying. If I understand correctly, It is OK to compare the probabilities even if they are from different models and their probabilities do not add up to 1.  The probabilities from the models are of different range. For example, The probability range for Product A is 0 to 0.80 while the probability range for Product B is 0 to 0.20. If I choose the greater of the two for each customer, I will end up choosing Product A for most customers. I would like to know if there is any better way to choose to avoid the same product for most customers.

Comment: Please expand some more on why you want to "avoid the same product for most customers." Customers are more likely to buy Product A and less likely to buy B. So it's appropriate to choose Product A in most cases; if in some cases you find that Product B is better then you have accomplished something useful. Should there be additional costs or benefits (for example, Product B has a higher profit margin so you want to steer customers in that direction), then you need to specify what those costs/benefits are (those may best determine probability weights) and edit your question accordingly.